# How to show that $\psi(x,y)=g(x)+y$ is a diffeomorphism?

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $E$ be a Banach space and $E_1,E_2$ be two close subspaces of $E$. We say $E=E_1\oplus E_2$ if $\varphi:E_1\times E_2 \to E$, $\varphi (u,v)=u+v$ is a linear continuous, invertible map.

The problem comes in two parts:

> Show: If $E=E_1\oplus E_2$ then $w=u+v$ for unique $u\in E_1$, and $v\in E_2$. And show that the projections $pr_{i}:E\to E_i$, $i=1,2$ given by $pr_{1}(u+v)=u$, $pr_{2}(u+v)=v$ are continuous.

This part is easy: given $w\in E$ since $\varphi$ is onto there is $(u,v)\in E_1\times E_2$ such that $u+v=w$. Now since $\varphi$ is injective this representation is unique. Note that $\varphi(u,0)=pr_{1}(w)$ so each projection is continuous.

> Let $V$ an open set of $F$ a Banach space, $a\in V$ and $g:V\to E$ a map of class $C^p$ such that $g'(a):F\to E$ is an isomorphism of $F$, and $E_{1,2}$ be a close subspaces of $E$. Suppose $E=E_1\oplus E_2$. Show $\psi:V\times E_2\to E$given by $\psi(x,y)=g(x)+y$ is a local diffeomorphism of class $C^p$ in $(a,0)$.

Please any help with this problem!! Thanks